# Haskell: Order-Insensitive Functional Application

Tags: haskell, exception, functional-programming

I want to implement an order-insensitive version of functional application in Haskell. By way of a little background: a prominent tradition in the semantics of natural language (deriving from Richard Montague, among others) assigns lambda functions of various types as the semantic values (sv's) of expressions.  The truth-value of a sentence is computed by performing functional application on the sv's of the sentence's constituents.  For a simple example, consider:

```
tl = [1..10]

bill :: Int
bill = 1

tall :: Int -> Bool
tall = \x -> x `elem` tl
```

Think of the sentence 'Bill is tall' as a tree with the left leaf occupied by 'Bill' and the right leaf occupied by 'tall'.  We compute the truth-value of the sentence by applying the sv of the **right** leaf to the sv of the **left** leaf. Now consider 'Some man is tall': here the left leaf is occupied by `some man' [the sv of which is of type :: (Int -> Bool) -> Bool] and the right leaf is occupied by 'tall' [the sv of which is of type :: (Int -> Bool)].  We compute the truth-value of the sentence by applying the sv of the **left** leaf to the sv of the **right** leaf.

So, in this system, given a tree with left leaf *a* and right leaf *b*, we **first** check which leaf is in the domain of the other, and **then** apply functional application accordingly: if *a* is in the domain of *b*, we do *b(a)*, whereas if *b* is in the domain of *a*, we do *a(b)*.

How would I implement this kind of "order-insensitive" functional application in Haskell?  I have written some functions that determine which leaf is in the domain of the other by parsing the result of

```
show (typeOf a)
```

for a leaf a.  However, this seems to me unnecessarily cumbersome.  Ghci gives an error if you try to e.g. evaluate

```
bill tall
```

So a simple way to check which item is in the domain of the other would be to just try applying one item to the other, and seeing whether an error/exception results.  My question, then, is: how do I catch exceptions which result from a type-mismatch?  That is, how do I catch non-IO exceptions of this sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't catch a type mismatch at run time; it's a compile-time error.  (At least, not without using ghc-api to compile code at runtime.  `ghci` is a wrapper around ghc-api, which is why it can do this.)  You would need to find a way to capture this type distinction in an ADT to do it at runtime, or possibly use a typeclass (this introduces other complications, though).

Answer (score 6):

You may get a long way with some type-class extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}

class Copula l r where
  type Sem l r :: *
  is :: l -> r -> Sem l r

instance Copula (a -> b) a where
  type Sem (a -> b) a = b
  is = ($)

instance Copula a (a -> b) where
  type Sem a (a -> b) = b
  is = flip ($)
```

For example, if we now define

```
bill :: Int
bill = 1

tall :: Int -> Bool
tall = \x -> x `elem` tl

someMan :: (Int -> Bool) -> Bool
someMan = flip any [1 .. 20]

allMan :: (Int -> Bool) -> Bool
allMan = flip all [1 .. 20]
```

we get

```
> bill `is` tall
True

> someMan `is` tall
True

> allMan `is` tall
False
```

Straightforwardly, with

```
are :: Copula l r => l -> r -> Sem l r
are = is
```

we can do

```
> someMan `are` tall
True

> allMan `are` tall
False
```

which may look a bit nicer.

**Note:** although this looks neat, in general, in polymorphic contexts the type checker needs quite some help figuring out what to do. For example

```
> [] `is` null

<interactive>:37:4:                                                              
    No instance for (Copula [a0] ([a1] -> Bool))
      arising from a use of `is'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Copula [a0] ([a1] -> Bool))
    In the expression: [] `is` null
    In an equation for `it': it = [] `is` null
```

while

```
> ([] :: [Int]) `is` (null :: [Int] -> Bool)
True
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!  I think I'll pursue this strategy then.